# div toggling not working how i want it to

Tags: javascript, jquery

please take a look at my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e8hj27gf/21/

You can see i have a display and hide function, How can i toggle this on and off, using one click event? please keep in mind i require the functionality of being able to close the div if the user clicks outside of it intact.

My Javascript:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

      var container = $("#boxwrapper");

       $("#toggleon").click(function (e) {

            if (!container.is(':visible'))
                Display();
       });

       $("#toggleoff").click(function (e) {

            if (container.is(':visible'))
                Hide();
       });



       $(document).mouseup(function (e) {

           if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
                if (container.is(':visible'))
                    Hide();
             }

        });                       
    });

    function Display() {
            $("#boxwrapper").show();
            $("#boxwrapper").addClass("box");              
        }

   function Hide() {
            $("#boxwrapper").hide();           
   }
```

I hope that makes sense!

Comment: do you mean that you want to hide the "show" link when the div is showing, only showing the "hide" link, and vice versa?

Comment: no i would like it to be a single link, that i can toggle the div on and off while keeping the stuff to hide the div when the user clicks out of it working

Answer (score 0):

Answer: http://jsfiddle.net/e8hj27gf/25/

**JavaScript_**

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#toggle").click(function(){
             $("#boxwrapper").fadeToggle("slow");  
        });       
    });
```

**CSS**

```
#boxwrapper
    {
        width: 100%;
        margin: auto;
        top: 0px;
        left: 20%;
        right: 0px;
        bottom: 0px;
        background-color: white;
        opacity: 0.4;
        position: fixed;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        overflow-x: scroll;
        display:none;
    }
```

**HTML**

```
    <div id="main">
        <a href='#' id='toggle'>Toggle</a>
    </div>

    <div id="boxwrapper">
    </div>
```

Search up the jQuery library, specifically toggle().. `fadeToggle()`, `slideToggle()` etc. etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is working but you took out the par that hides the div when clicking outside of it... can it work with it?

Comment: Yes, its just a matter of setting a click event anywhere else on the screen except the grey one. I'll update the fiddle

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to use is the jQuery .toggle() method.

See: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

eg:

```
function ShowHide() {
        $("#boxwrapper").toggle();
        $("#boxwrapper").addClass("box");              
    }
```